# How to add a persistence volume claim having mongodb database in a deploymentset to be consumed by a nodejs microservice deployed in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb

I am planning to use this mongodb from my nodejs microservice which is deployed on a kubernetes cluster. Also i am little confused whether statefulset is the right way. Can someone give me proper answer and who has tried this with a persistence volume claim in a deploymentset with a mongodb database.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body.